# show hide div based on mysql table row value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

hi guys im trying to show and hide div according to mysql value but i couldnt do it can you help me what im doing wrong 
here is my code thanks a lot for your ideas

```
var Value = <?php echo json_encode($valuek) ?>;
if (Value==1){
$('#show_hide').show();
}
else{
$('#show_hide').hide();
}


<?php
$valuek = $session->userinfo['vcc'];
?>

<div id="show_hide">
some code
</div>
```

Comment: Is `$valuek` an array or a simple string?  What is it's expected values?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo json_encode($valuek) ?>
```

will return a json string, instead try just using "echo"

```
<?php echo $valuek ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are going for is a boolean value then there is simply no need for JSON.

Echo the value directly into the JavaScript. Remember to ensure you are passing a valid boolean value.

---

PHP code -

```
<?php
  $showDiv = ($dbValue == 1? 'true' : 'false');
?>
```

---

JavaScript + PHP injection -

```
<script>
 var value = '<?php echo $showDiv; ?>';
<script>
```

Don't forget to wrap the PHP injected value with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$valuek = $session->userinfo['vcc'];
```

I'm not sure if you have the code in this order in your php file, or just showed pieces of code in this order, but Should go BEFORE your js code. It has no value when js code is run.

To see what $valuek is, just echo it on top of the screen

```
 <?php echo "<h1>$valuek</h1>" ?>.
```

Or just look at the source - at your js function, to see what is printed after 'var Value ='
That's the main thing really - to make sure that you getting what you expect from session.

And as been said, you don't need jason_encode, but you do need a semi-colon after echo command.
Also, I hope your jquery code is within $(document).ready function, not as is.